# Should Gradle's buildSrc folder be committed to source code repo?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Sorry for the naive question. I am new to Gradle.
Conceptually, it looks like we should commit the buildSrc folder to repo but I see some temp files as well in that folder, which led me to ask this question - Should we commit the entire buildSrc folder to the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buildSrc` can be used to abstract imperative logic. In other words, declutter your main Gradle build files.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources

The `buildSrc` folder is basically another Gradle project. So things you would normally ignored for a Gradle project, should also be ignored from the `buildSrc` project.

If you have logic defined in `buildSrc` that is required for your project, then yes it should be committed. If not, then that folder should be deleted entirely to avoid Gradle attempting to automatically build it.